# How to Update TableView and its parent ScrollView Height according to its content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, swift3.2

I have a `UITableView` that is set to not enable scrolling, and it exists in a `UIScrollView`. I'm doing it this way as the design specs call for something that looks like a `tableView`. The `TableView` Cell having dynamic height So I use

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Now once I fetched data from API and before Reloading TableView.

I update height constraint of both `tableView` and `ScrollView`. But height does not get update. I used the below code

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
tvHeightConstraint.constant = tvPrdtDetail.contentSize.height
svHeightConstraint.constant = tvPrdtDetail.contentSize.height + 8
```

Here `tvHeightConstraint` and `svHeightConstraint` are height constraint of `tableView` and `ScrollView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var tvHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var svHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Log always show 0 when I print `TableView` `ContentSize`

```
  print("Content Size: \(tvPrdtDetail.contentSize.height)")
```

Please help me out . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Re order like this as call to `layoutIfNeeded` should be after updating the constants of the constraints

```
tvHeightConstraint.constant = tvPrdtDetail.contentSize.height 
svHeightConstraint.constant = tvPrdtDetail.contentSize.height + 8  //  remove this 
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Also no need for 2nd line as if you hook constraints properly in the scrollview from top to bottom updating height constraint of the table will update  the scrollview

**Edit:**

1- give the table height constraint say 3000 ( some big number ) followed by `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

2- reload the table

3- get the y frame of the last cell

4- assign it to the height constraint

5- layout the view

do this after you get the data

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I tried, but no change in results

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope so this will work.Call this when you need constraint should update,And `override updateConstraints` function

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()

override public func updateConstraints() {
    super.updateConstraints()
    tvHeightConstraint.constant = tvPrdtDetail.contentSize.height
    svHeightConstraint.constant = tvPrdtDetail.contentSize.height + 8
}
```